# Configure 4-4 Tabla for Bansuri Practice

Tags: practice, rhythm, percussion, indian-classical, bansuri

The video below (starting at 2:50) shows the Instructor turning on the 4-4 Tabla player.

How did he configure the Tabla player? He's a wonderful Instructor, but rather vague on these points.

In my case, I will likely get a computer/app-based Tabla player.

What is the best way to configure it? For instance, when I download various tabla players for Andriod, it lists various `taals` and it shows numerous hand-dials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following three parameters need to be configured:

**The Shruti** (Drone, or the reference note for music that is played)

In the flute that is included in your question, it is **E** (White key 3rd)

**The Taal**

It determines the number of beats per cycle, and the sounds of those beats

**The Speed**

Speed of the cycle-how fast does one whole cycle complete.

One may find two settings in this category.

*Cyclic Time Period*: It lets you mechanically compress or expand the Taal cycle without changing the sounds in the Taal. It's like controlling the speed of a fan or a wheel.

*Laya*: It lets you select a slower version of the same Taal, which changes the sounds of the beats chosen in that Taal.